# remove active class on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm working on a site that has a single page navigation with smooth scroll. The user clicks a link and is scrolled down the page to that section. I have the smooth scrolling working and the active class being added to the appropriate sections.

What I am having trouble with is if a user clicks the link and is scrolled down to that section, the active class remains if the user simply scrolls away, therefore showing an active link when they may not be in that section.

I basically need to remove the active class if the user scrolls away from that section.

You can check the site here:

http://www.paynecocraft.com/

Here is the JS for the active class addition.

```
$(document).on("scroll", onScroll);

    function onScroll(event){
        var scrollPos = $(document).scrollTop();
        $('#menubar a').each(function () {
            var currLink = $(this);
            var refElement = $(currLink.attr("href"));
            if (refElement.position().top <= scrollPos &&     refElement.position().top + refElement.height() > scrollPos) {
                $('#menubar ul li a').removeClass("active");
                currLink.addClass("active");
            }
            else{
                currLink.removeClass("active");
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: I should have added that I would like the active class to be added on scroll to. You'll notice if you just scroll the page, the active class doesn't get added.

Comment: Why write this yourself when there are so many good solutions out there for this. One being http://davist11.github.io/jQuery-One-Page-Nav/?

Comment: I'd start with the fact that `menubar` is a class in the HTML and not an id...